# Why isn't my Angular directive correctly binding one of my fields?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wanted to create a directive to create sortable table headers. The headers appear to be rendered and clicking on them cause the sort order to be toggled between ascending/descending like I'd expect, but the sorted column never changes.

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', [])

angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('sortableheader', function () {
        return {
            template: '<thead><tr><th ng-repeat="col in ctrl.columns"><a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.orderByField = \'{{col.field}}\';ctrl.sortDesc = !ctrl.sortDesc">{{col.name}}<span ng-show="ctrl.orderByField == \'{{col.field}}\' && ctrl.sortDesc" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span><span ng-show="ctrl.orderByField == \'{{col.field}}\' && !ctrl.sortDesc" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span></a></th></tr></thead> '
            ,
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                columns: '=',
                orderByField: '=',
                sortDesc: '=',
            },
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            bindToController: true,
            controller: function () {
                var vm = this;
                // Any additional functionality?                
            }
        }
    });

(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp')
           .controller('SampleController', SampleController);
    

    function SampleController() {
        var vm = this;
        
        vm.orderByField = 'col1';
        vm.sortDesc = true;
         
        vm.data = [
          {col1: 'ABC', col2: '123'},
          {col1: 'XYZ', col2: '321'},
          {col1: 'GHI', col2: '234'},
          {col1: 'DEF', col2: '456'},
                  ];
      
        vm.columns = [
            { name: 'Column 1', field: 'col1' },
            { name: 'Column 2', field: 'col2' },            
        ];
    }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="SampleController as report">
  Order by: {{report.orderByField}}
  <table>
       <sortableheader columns="report.columns" orderByField="report.orderByField" sort-desc="report.sortDesc"></sortableheader>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="d in report.data | orderBy:report.orderByField:report.sortDesc">
            <td>{{d.col1}}</td>                                        
            <td>{{d.col2}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>   
  </table>
</div>
```

Where am I going wrong with this? I'm sure it's some scoping issue (as it always seems to be), but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put col.field in quotes - see updated code

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', [])

angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('sortableheader', function () {
        return {
            template: '<thead><tr><th ng-repeat="col in ctrl.columns"><a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.orderByField = col.field;ctrl.sortDesc = !ctrl.sortDesc">{{col.name}}<span ng-show="ctrl.orderByField == \'{{col.field}}\' && ctrl.sortDesc" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span><span ng-show="ctrl.orderByField == \'{{col.field}}\' && !ctrl.sortDesc" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span></a></th></tr></thead> '
            ,
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                columns: '=',
                orderByField: '=',
                sortDesc: '=',
            },
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            bindToController: true,
            controller: function () {
                var vm = this;
                // Any additional functionality?                
            }
        }
    });

(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp')
           .controller('SampleController', SampleController);
    

    function SampleController() {
        var vm = this;
        
        vm.orderByField = 'col1';
        vm.sortDesc = true;
         
        vm.data = [
          {col1: 'ABC', col2: '123'},
          {col1: 'XYZ', col2: '321'},
          {col1: 'GHI', col2: '234'},
          {col1: 'DEF', col2: '456'},
                  ];
      
        vm.columns = [
            { name: 'Column 1', field: 'col1' },
            { name: 'Column 2', field: 'col2' },            
        ];
    }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="SampleController as report">
  Order by: {{report.orderByField}}
  <table>
       <sortableheader columns="report.columns" order-by-field="report.orderByField" sort-desc="report.sortDesc"></sortableheader>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="d in report.data | orderBy:report.orderByField:report.sortDesc">
            <td>{{d.col1}}</td>                                        
            <td>{{d.col2}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>   
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I know I had tried that in my real code but it didn't work. But from the sample, it seems to. So now I get to try to figure out what's different between the code I posted here any my production code. Thanks for the help!